# When is mandatory use TestEntityManager in testing?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Having a Spring Boot app, working with Spring Data JPA and H2 configured, it for sample/academic purposes.

a Repository is defined as:

```
public interface PersonaRepository extends CrudRepository<Persona, String> {

}
```

and then the following test

```
@ActiveProfiles(profiles={"h2"})
@DataJpaTest
class PersonaRepositorySliceTests {

    @Autowired
    private PersonaRepository personaRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

    @Test
    void countTest() {
        long count = personaRepository.count();
        assertThat(count).isEqualTo(33);

        count = testEntityManager.getEntityManager()
                                 .createQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Persona p")
                                 .getResultList().size();
        System.out.println("count: " + count);//prints 1
        //assertThat(count).isEqualTo(33);//fails

        count = testEntityManager.getEntityManager()
                                 .createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM persona")
                                 .getResultList().size();

        System.out.println("count: " + count);//prints 1
        assertThat(count).isEqualTo(33);//fails
    }

}
```

The

```
long count = personaRepository.count();
assertThat(count).isEqualTo(33);
```

pass, therefore the `@Entity` classes were detected and of course the `schema-h2.sql` and `data-h2.sql` scripts were executed as expected.

Now the confusion is why

- `.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Persona p")`
- `.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM persona")`

Works **but** always returns 1, why not 33 how is expected?

*"Seems"* that `TestEntityManager` in some way is **not** working with the data loaded by the `data-h2.sql` file.

**Secondary** question:

- Is it the expected behaviour?

Even if is yes, why is returned 1 and not 0? or is mandatory an extra configuration?

I read some tutorials about `@DataJpaTest` and `TestEntityManager`, among them, main source:

- [Auto-configured Data JPA Tests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test)

The former is a slice test and the latter is an alternative of `EntityManager` for test.
In other tutorials I saw many examples of `TestEntityManager` working with `persist` and later retrieving the data (for 1 or more entities) within the same `@Test`, so the insertion was accomplished manually.

**Main Question:**

- So when is necessary work with the `TestEntityManager` type (approach) over the Custom `CrudRepository<T,ID>` approach for testing purposes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The underlying issue has nothing to do with Spring Boot/Hibernate or your test setup.

The SQL statement `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Person` returns a single row with a single column that contains the number of counted rows:

```
$ SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Person;

COUNT(*)  
----
4
```

That's why you have to call `.getSingleResult()` from the result for your native or custom query:

```
assertThat(personRepository.count())
  .isEqualTo(4);

assertThat(testEntityManager.getEntityManager()
                            .createQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Person p", Long.class)
                            .getSingleResult())
  .isEqualTo(4L);

assertThat(testEntityManager.getEntityManager()
                            .createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Person")
                            .getSingleResult())
  .isEqualTo(BigInteger.valueOf(4));
```

Spring Data JPA does the exact same thing under the hood for `.count()`:

```
public long count() {
    return (Long)this.em.createQuery(this.getCountQueryString(), Long.class).getSingleResult();
}
```

You can also directly inject the `EntityManager` for your `@DataJpaTest` test and don't need the `TestEntityManager` for this:

```
@DataJpaTest
class ApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

  @Autowired
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Autowired
  private PersonRepository personRepository;

  @Test
  void contextLoads() {

    assertThat(personRepository.count())
      .isEqualTo(4);

    //With TestEntityManager

    assertThat(testEntityManager.getEntityManager()
                                .createQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Person p", Long.class)
                                .getSingleResult())
      .isEqualTo(4L);

    assertThat(testEntityManager.getEntityManager()
                                .createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Person")
                                .getSingleResult())
      .isEqualTo(BigInteger.valueOf(4));

     //With EntityManager

    assertThat(entityManager.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Person p", Long.class)
                            .getSingleResult())
      .isEqualTo(4L);

    assertThat(entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Person")
                            .getSingleResult())
      .isEqualTo(BigInteger.valueOf(4));
  }

}
```

The `TestEntityManager` provides helper methods to e.g. do a persist/flush/find operation (flush the in-memory persistence context and read the same entity from the database) with a single-liner. The `TestEntityManager` is never *mandatory*.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was so tired so I got this situation. Consider to expand a little more the information for `TestEntityManager` - about when mandatory or valuable to use it

Comment: the `TestEntityManager` is never **mandatory**. It helps e.g. to test the full cycle of storing a JPA entity and retrieving it (flush the in-memory persistence context and read the same entity from the database). More information can be found at the Javadoc of the class

Comment: Consider to add your comment in the post. It to complement your information for the audience.

Comment: I can flush the persistence-context on a normal `EntityManager` ant the documentation of `TestEntityManager` says that its flush-method is just delegating to `EntityManager`, so `flush` is not a reason to use the Test-version.